# Match with Phrase for Google Speech API

Tags: nlp, google-speech-api

I capture an audio from a speaker where they say - `"I want to meet John Disilva"`. I pass this to Google Speech API with Phrase as `{ 'John Disilva', 'Ashish Mundra'}`. However, Google Speech API returns me full phrase i.e. - `'I want to meet John Disilva'`.

Is there a way I can only get my phrase as return value as I am only interested to extract the name part?

The reason is that I cannot control what someone is saying to my mic. They can say `'I would like to see John Disilva'` or `'Do you know John Disilva'`, but I am sure that my user will always have that name somewhere in this sentence which I want to extract.

If Google Speech API can give me the exact phrase via which it was able to detect `John Disilva` in that sentence then I can use that Phrase for further processing in my code.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with the Google Speech API.  Your best bet may be to just do post-processing to see which name is present.  If you need something more accurate than that look for an ASR system that supports "keyword spotting."